# getBytes("UCS-2") returns different results in different devices with different API levels

Tags: android, string, byte, android-8.1-oreo

currently I have a problem with the following code:

```
String a = "0932300090";
byte[] b = a.getBytes(Charset.forName("UCS-2"));
Log.d("MTINH",Arrays.toString(b));
```

This code has been used in two different devices, one is running Android 8.0, another one is running Android 8.1, and I got two different results:

in Android 8.0:

> -1, -2, 48, 0, 57, 0, 51, 0, 50, 0, 51, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 57, 0, 48, 0

in Android 8.1:

> -2, -1, 0, 48, 0, 57, 0, 51, 0, 50, 0, 51, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 57, 0, 48

it seems that the result is swapped by pair: [-1 -2] vs [-2 -1]... [48 0] vs [0 48].

So what is the problem here ? Anything changed from Java or Android ?

Comment: Seems to be an endianess issue.

Comment: @MinasMina yes, this problem related to ByteOrder LITTLE_ENDIAN & BIG_ENDIAN

Comment: The first two bytes are a byte order mark (BOM) which specifies the endianness. So even when the stream of bytes is different it should not be a problem for the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

***UCS-2 encoding*** is effectively `UTF-16` on **Android 8.x and 9.0**. On Android 8.1, android engineering the following change to UTF-16 encoding.

*Note that BOM marker (-2, -1) is included in the output. If you need a consistent result across device, you could use UTF-16BE optionally. The below is the details of the behavior change.*

**UTF-16 Charset output byte-ordering**

The `UTF-16` Charset (obtained via `java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-16")` or `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_16`) now encodes strings into big-endian UTF-16 bytes with a byte-order marker, as the javadoc says it does.
Previously, it encoded as little-endian with a byte-order marker, in contradiction to the documentation.

This also changes the result of calling `getBytes("UTF-16")` on a String.
This makes no difference to code which uses the `UTF-16` Charset to encode and decode strings, since decoding obeys the byte-order marker. It only affects code which uses the `UTF-16` Charset to encode and then assumes that the resulting bytes are little-endian, for example by decoding them using a mechanism that ignores the byte-order marker.

Users wanting to encode as little-endian with a byte-order marker can use the `x-UTF-16LE-BOM` Charset. (Note that this Charset should not be used for decoding bytes unless they are known to be little-endian.)